# Mail sending through c#.Net getting error

Tags: c#

I want to select file and send to employees.
employee's(recipient) email I am reading from excel.
Sender's email is set to my code.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attach));
mail.To.Add(sendmail);
mail.From = new MailAddress(SenderEmail);
mail.Subject = "Payroll";
string body = "Hi, payroll";
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendermail", "pwd");
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Now I want to read sender's email & password from a textbox,and pass.
Now error occuring like this

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
>   Learn more at

I coded smtpclient host as gmail and corresponding port.
But I want to send from other account means in yahoo,live etc..
How can it possible? But even gmail is also giving error.Can anybody help?
error is getting when reading from textbox

Comment: Are "sendermail" and "pwd" actually in your code, or just sample values?

Comment: Can you try port 465 and see if you get the same error?  I'm pretty sure 587 is TLS and 465 is SSL.

Comment: Try setting smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network. Port 587 should be fine.

Comment: @MikePrecup it is sample.

Comment: you should try 587 to 465